# C to Python via Ctypes - Wrapping Struct of Function Pointers to Static Functions

Tags: python, c, struct, function-pointers, ctypes

I have structs in a C library that are like this.
The function pointers in DataFn point to static functions.

.h

```
struct Data {
    int i;
    int *array;
};

typedef struct {
    bool (* const fn1) (struct Data*, const char *source);
    ....
} DataFn;
extern DataFn const DATAFUNC
```

Using objdump, the table only contains DATAFUNC and a few other things from gcc.

This is fine in C where calling fn1 would go like DATAFUNC.fn1(..., ...), but how would something like this be wrapped around so fn1 can be called in python w/ ctypes?

Example python

```
libc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("./data.so")
print(libc.DATAFUNC)
```

results in 
`<_FuncPtr object at 0x6ffffcd7430>`

[This is similar, but there isn't a factory function.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854388/interacting-with-a-c-struct-containing-only-function-pointers-using-ctypes-in-py)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes) contains everything required to solve this problem.

I believe that the main piece missing, was the *in_dll* method of a *CTypes* type (***Accessing values exported from dll*** section).

Other than that, in order to work with *C* data, you need to let *Python* know of the data format. That applies to:

- *struct*s. Define *Python* counterparts by subclassing
  *ctypes.Structure*
- Function pointers (applies to your case). Define them using *ctypes.CFUNCTYPE*

I prepared a simplified example that illustrates the above. Note that I didn't do any error handling (checking for *NULL*s (which **you should**)), to keep things simple.

*dll00.h*:

```c
struct Data {
    int i;
};


typedef struct {
    int (* const Func00Ptr) (struct Data*, const char*);
} DataFunc;


extern DataFunc const dataFunc;
```

*dll00.c*:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "dll00.h"


static int func00(struct Data *pData, const char *source)
{
    printf("From C - Data.i: [%d], source: [%s]\n", pData->i, source);
    return -255;
}


DataFunc const dataFunc = { &func00 };
```

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes as ct
import sys


DLL_NAME = "./dll00.{:s}".format("dll" if sys.platform[:3].lower() == "win" else "so")


class Data(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = (
        ("i", ct.c_int),
    )


Func00Type = ct.CFUNCTYPE(ct.c_int, ct.POINTER(Data), ct.c_char_p)


class DataFunc(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = (
        ("func00", Func00Type),
    )


def main(*argv):
    data = Data(127)
    dll = ct.CDLL(DLL_NAME)
    data_func = DataFunc.in_dll(dll, "dataFunc")
    ret = data_func.func00(ct.byref(data), "abcd".encode())
    print("Function returned: {:d}".format(ret))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q049962265]> ~/sopr.sh
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> dll00.c  dll00.h  code00.py
> [064bit prompt]> gcc -shared -fPIC -o dll00.so dll00.c
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> dll00.c  dll00.h  code.py  dll00.so
> [064bit prompt]> objdump -t dll00.so | grep dataFunc
> 0000000000200e10 g     O .data.rel.ro   0000000000000008              dataFunc
> [064bit prompt]> python code00.py
> Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] 064bit on linux
>
> From C - Data.i: [127], source: [abcd]
> Function returned: -255
>
> Done.
> ```